# $('#<form name> input[name=<field>]').val() returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<s:form action="editDispositionMatrix" namespace="/" 
id="editDispositionMatrix" >
  <s:textarea name="otherReason"  cols="50" rows="5" ></s:textarea>
</s:form>


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $('#editDispositionMatrix').submit(function(){

    var otherReason1 = $('#editDispositionMatrix 
    input[name=otherReason]').val();       //getting undefined
    var otherReason2 =  $('[name="otherReason"]').val();                                   
    //getting right value
  });

</script>
```

This is a sample code in a jsp which is a model window. It was prevously using `$('#editDispositionMatrix input[name=otherReason]').val()` for reading a value from a text area entered by the user. Now we are getting value as undefined. But when we used  `$('[name="otherReason"]').val();` we got the right value. What can be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: `<s:textarea>` creates a `<textarea></textarea>`, right?

Comment: Wrap the attribute value in quotes `$('#editDispositionMatrix input[name="otherReason"]').val();`

Comment: it should be `$('#editDispositionMatrix textarea[name=otherReason]')`

Comment: Try using `:input[name=otherReason]` or `textarea[name=otherReason]`

Comment: oh..ya..right..thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have an `<input>` to select. Use

```
$('#editDispositionMatrix textarea[name=otherReason]').val()
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

the reason because it is not an `input` field, rather it is `textarea`, it should be like

```
$('#editDispositionMatrix textarea[name=otherReason]')
```